Can the criteria of convergence be seperated from the idea of a limit?
In general topological spaces, the limit value that a sequence converges to is not unique. So, using the limit value to express convergence seems inappropriate to me. Due to the fact that whether it is converges or not should be independent some specific choice of point.
For an extreme example, consider the trivial topology. In it, every sequences converges to any point, so I think it is better to talk about some sort of set that a sequence converges into than a specific point.
Is it possible to talk about whether or not a topological sequence converges to "somewhere" without ever actually ever taking specific points?

I am not sure I understood correctly your question. Does the notion of "having limits points" do the job you ask? Or maybe, when you can use the notion of Cauchy sequence (for instance, in metric spaces), you can say to have the Cauchy property.

@fspa Cauchy sequences are not always convergent though. And we have that term in metric spaces (well, not only, but not in every topological space), where the limit is unique anyway. I'm also not really sure I understood the question.

I'm sorry but can you clarify your question more?

It's hard to say. Would you be happy with something like "$(x_n)$ converges iff the set $\bigcap_{S} \mathrm{cl} ({x_k : k \in S})$ is nonempty (where $S$ ranges over all infinite subsets of $\Bbb N$)"? In other words, if the intersection of the closures of all subsequences is nonempty. This is a bit of an artificial re-phrasing of "there exists some $x$ such that $x_n \to x$".

I think you mean the trivial/indiscrete topology, not the discrete topology. The discrete topology is Hausdorff and metrisable and so on, so limits are unique.

This entire thing is confusing. Certainly you can just say a given sequence/net is convergent without mentioning to what point/s does it converge to. What exactly is the question here?

But how do you talk about converges without reference to a specific point @DavidGao

@trystwithfreedom Just say the sequence converges? I’m not sure I understand your point. Like, what is unsatisfactory about just saying “the sequence/net $(a_n)$ converges” or that “the sequence/net $(a_n)$ is convergent”?

Btw, given that I’m still unsure what exactly the question is, I’m not sure whether this is relevant, but note that, while the topology can be retrieved from what nets are convergent and to what limits they converge to if they are convergent - namely, a subset $A$ is closed iff all convergent nets of elements of $A$ have all their limits contained in $A$. The same is not true if the only information we have is what nets are convergent without knowing their limits - for example, on the space of two points, both the trivial topology and Sierpiński topology satisfy that all nets are convergent.
